# Wait for Workbook.RefreshAll() (C#)

Tags: c#, excel

I want to loop through a directory (using C#) and Refresh all Excel sheets in there. I use:

```
Workbook.RefreshAll();
```

How can I wait for the `Workbook.RefreshAll()` statement to finish?
The problem is: I open `FileA`, `then Workbook.RefreshAll()` and then open `FileB` - Refresh for `FileA` is terminated. The only solution I found is to call something like

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
```

which I found very unlovely...

Does someone know a better way to wait?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel vba refresh wait](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925403/excel-vba-refresh-wait)

Answer (score 4):

Updated 31.05.2016...

Thanks for your help. I found the following solution:

```
foreach (MSExcel.WorkbookConnection cnn in wb.Connections)
{
    if (cnn.Type.ToString() == "xlConnectionTypeODBC")
    {
        cnn.ODBCConnection.BackgroundQuery = false;
    }
    else
    {
        cnn.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = false;
    }
}
```

Frank

Comment: You are updating every workbook connection once for every sheet, the outer loop is pointless.

Comment: This always returns error: System.ArgumentException: 'The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))'

Answer (score 3):

**The below code will work perfectly when your excel has to run background query to pull data from SQL Server/MS Access and it will wait for the query is successful.**

```
public void RefreshSheet(Excel.Application Excel, Excel.Workbook WB)
{
    WB.RefreshAll();
    Excel.Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone();
    WB.save();
}
```

Here WB is the workbook and Excel is the Excel Application.

Answer (score 2):

If you go through your `Workbook` and set the the `BackgroundQuery` property of all of your `QueryTable`s to `false`, `RefreshAll` should finish before moving on.

```
foreach (Worksheet worksheet in workbook.Worksheets)
{
    foreach (QueryTable table in worksheet.QueryTables)
        table.BackgroundQuery = false;
}

//This will finish executing before moving on
workbook.RefreshAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can query for the State:

Application.CalculationState =xldone

For Documentation look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb220901(v=office.12).aspx