# Powershell excel refresh fails with "Call Was Rejected by Callee" when .visible=$false

Tags: excel, powershell, com

I've had this issue for a long time now and had just ignored it out of laziness, however I now need to find a solution. I have a script which automates refreshing a large number of excel documents. This works well and dandy, however, it fails if I have the Visible property set to false on workbooks which are stored on a network share.

To reiterate, refreshing with the visible property set to false works fine on LOCAL files, but any workbook saved on a \ location fails with an error "Call was rejected by callee". All refreshes work fine with the visible property set to true.

Here is my code :

```psh
#Create Excel COM object and set it up for use.
$excel = new-object -comobject Excel.Application;
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false;
#If this is set to false, saving the file on a network share will fail. Reason : Unknown.
$excel.Visible = $true;
#Open workbook which should be refreshed. 
$excelworkbook = $excel.workbooks.Open($workbook);
#Refresh WB
$excelworkbook.RefreshAll();
#Save
$excelworkbook.Save();
#Quit Excel
$excel.Quit();
#Destroy COM object. (VERY IMPORTANT!!!!!)
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel);
```

I have tried the following :

1. Adding Start-Sleep 30 between creating the excel object and setting the visible property
2. Setting visible before DisplayAlerts
3. Wishing really hard for it to just work

Any ideas?

Comment: You say that it does it for a large number of files, do you create a new Excel com object for each file? Or do you open Excel, and then loop through files with a Open/Refresh/Close file cycle before exiting Excel and releasing the com object?

Comment: I create it, do my loop, then close it. 
The example I gave is condensed without the loop. The whole script is pretty long.

Comment: Does Excel need credentials to access the network location?  Does a credentials prompt appear when `Visible` is true?

Comment: Excellent question, but no. It does require authentication, but it's handled via a normal domain ACL. (So no login prompts or username/PW input).

Comment: Add your `Start-Sleep 30` statement between `RefreshAll()` and `Save()`

Comment: My scenario is not the same as yours as even for a local file I can repro the issue; therefore I am not sure if the workaround worked for me will also work for you: it seems simply adding sleep between `$excelworkbook.RefreshAll()` and `$excelworkbook.Save()` works.

Comment: Very interesting... I actually end up with an error as soon as I call open($workbook)... Maybe it has to do with excel version as well then. What are you testing with @wangzq? I am using powershell v4 and excel 2014.

Comment: @Ethan, I simply added a simple database query from my local sql server, then created two copies of the excel file on both local and a network share.

Comment: @wangzq, that's interesting... I just tried it out and you're right it did work! That's great! Want to post it as an answer so that I can mark you as correct?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Since you had the suggestion first do you want to add an answer here?

Comment: @Matt I've added an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `RefreshAll()` doesn't wait for the refresh to actually succeed in the background with `Visible = $False` set.

Introduce an artificial delay between `RefreshAll()` and `Save()`, like so:

```psh
$excelworkbook.RefreshAll();
Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
$excelworkbook.Save();
```

---

Alternatively, you might be able to force the `RefreshAll()` to execute synchronously by setting `BackgroundQuery = $False` on all query tables in your workbook, [as suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18789264/712649) to a similar question:

```psh
foreach ($Sheet in $excelworkbook.Worksheets) {
    foreach ($QTable in $Sheet.QueryTables) {
        $QTable.BackgroundQuery = $false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add a `DoEvents` block:

```
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
```

This will allow the queue to cycle through anything you've told Excel to do & then back to the script execution.  Another thing would be to set `UserControl = false` so that Excel is not *simply* hidden, but is clearly out of the user's ability to respond to events.

Lastly, there may be something about setting `Visible` after you've set other properties - it may be the case that Excel responds to the Visible event by toggling a few other things (don't remember off-hand, but something in the back of my brain says this is the case, or used to be).

Comment: `DoEvents()` did not change it for me.

Comment: It looks like the OP accepted that a `sleep` before saving solved the problem for them.  DoEvents should be the same thing, in that it releases Excel's place in the queue, but I can't explain the difference in the two.  That said: exact same problem?  If so, I'd been thinking that it might be about authentication anyway (timing out maybe).

Comment: I ended up with something like: 
```for($ctr = 1; $ctr -le 5; $ctr++) {
    try {
        write-output "attempting to resave to $outfile..."
        $wb.SaveAs($outfile, $xlSLSXType)
        $errorlevel = 0
        break
    } catch [System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException] {
        if($_.Exception.ErrorCode -eq 0x80010001) {
            sleep 0.25
        } else { throw }
    }
}```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used Powershell to open an Excel file, run a macro and then I wanted to check the data and edit it if I needed to. After that I saved the file.
My problem was that I didn´t press Enter key after typing something in a cell, so apparently it was still excecuting a process, which threw that exception.
I solved it using a try catch block, with a popup message to finish the cell edition, and then executing again the .SaveAs().

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35249483)