# Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone Crashes Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerbi, powerpivot

I have a OLAP Data Model that is published on the Power-BI Services. I built a report using `CUBE` formulas. I need to do a bit of Hiding and Showing Columns based on the `CUBEVALUE` results. And I need to print PDF's for a whole bunch of slicer selections. Naturally, I need my VBA Sub to wait until all the `CUBE` formulas finish refreshing.

I know that the `Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone` method will let me wait until the refresh completes. However, in Excel 2016, it just seems to crash excel. It just waits indefinitely.

Excel Version: **Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.13001.20254) 64-bit**

I faced the same issue with Power-Query Queries, but setting the `BackgroundQuery` property of all the Queries to `FALSE` before calling `Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone` solved the crashing problem. Unfortunately, the `BackgroundQuery` property cannot be set to `FALSE` for an OLAP Data Connection.

The following technique did not work either:

```
Do Until Application.CalculationState = xlDone
Loop
```

The refresh starts a bit late, and during that time the `Application.CalculationState` is `xlDone` and the code just does not wait for the refresh to even start. If I use the `Application.Wait` method, the Query also waits to refresh.

Is this just on my computer? Or, are all of you facing issues with `Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone`?
How have you worked around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been having a similar issue this but the commonality among all of my issues is that `Application.Calculation` was set to `xlCalculationManual` when `CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone` is triggered. Before that, I tried a series of `Calculate`, `CalculateFull`, and `CalculateFullRebuild` to no avail.

You may need to implement something like the following to get your script to work:

```
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone

        Do Until .CalculationState = xlDone
        Loop
        
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With
```